# jpg images without extension aren't displayed

Tags: kivy

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image

self.img = Image(source="image") # This works when image is an PNG image
self.img = Image(source="image.jpg") # This works when image.jpg is a JPG image
self.img = Image(source="image") # This doesn't work when image is a JPG image
```

I need to specify images without extention for the app to be generic (working with more image types). Can I achieve it somehow?

Comment: When `image` is a `JPG` file without the the `.jpg` extension, what does `imghdr,what("image")` return?

Comment: The `Image` code uses `imghdr` to determine the source file format when the file has no extension. In some cases, `imghdr` cannot determine the file format. Odd that you are encountering image files without the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy is using "imghdr" to determine the image type [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/image/__init__.py#L454), and as a fallback it uses the file extension [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/image/__init__.py#L438).

That explains why the image loads fine when it has a file extension, even though "imghdr" can't find the file type in the file's content.

I tested on a list of JPEG files, and each time "imghdr" was able to detect the file type each time. That is done [here im imghdr](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/imghdr.py#L37). Notably, "imghdr" does not consider the file extension.

```
$ python
>>> import os, imghdr
... for f in os.listdir('.'):
...     print('%s -- %s' % (f, imghdr.what(f)))
```

Maybe the JPEG file is missing the "JFIF" or "Exif" string that imghdr is looking for? You could use `hexedit` to see if one of those string is present at Byte 6 of the image file.

Comment: It means, I can't open the jpg file without extension?

Comment: If possible, you could try to re-create the JPEG. Open it in GIMP and export it again as JPEG. Maybe it was written in some JPEG dialct that Kivy doesn't understand well.

Comment: This is not possible, the images are downloaded from the Wikipedia and it's possible to display it only with extension. So, there isn't so programming trick? I have to test every file and according to type append appropriate extension to it?

Comment: You could use something like this to bulk rename JPEGs `for f in $(ls *) ; do r=$(file $f) ; ${r##*'JPEG image data'*} && mv "$f" "$f.jpg" ; done`. That is, if Bash's `file` command does recognize the images correctly as JPEGs.